# Powershell: Why does ("111" -match "111-XD") returns false and ("111-XD" -match "111") returns true

Tags: regex, powershell, match

It's probably a stupid question and forgive me if it has been asked somewhere else but why
does `("111" -match "111-XD")` returns false and `("111-XD" -match "111")` returns true?

It there a way to ignore the position of the operands in the comparison
Thanks

Comment: `-` is not a special character here. [The regex `111` matches within the string "111-XD"](https://regex101.com/r/86UO8T/1) however [the regex `111-XD` does not match within the string `"111"`](https://regex101.com/r/B59llS/1)

Comment: To answer your last question (*adding to VLAZ comment*), you can use a wildcard expression to accomplish what you're asking for: `'111-XD' -Like '111*'`. The `-Like` operator allows *wildcard expression* matching.

Answer (score 6):

The text after `-match` is a regular expression to match against, and the string `"111"` does not contain the pattern `"111-XD"`.

Conversely, the string `"111-XD"` *does* contain the pattern `"111"`. This shows that the `-match` operation is not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

How about like this?  One way is true.  Parentheses are not needed because of operator precedence (note that -and and -or uniquely have equal precedence).

```
'111' -match '111-XD' -or '111-XD' -match '111'

True
```